# Setting width to wrap_content for TextView through code

Tags: android, textview

Can anyone help me how to set the width of `TextView` to `wrap_content` through code and not from XML?

I am dynamically creating a `TextView` in code ,so is there anyway to how to set its width to `wrap_content` through code?

Answer (score 152):

```
TextView pf = new TextView(context);
pf.setLayoutParams(new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

For different layouts like `ConstraintLayout` and others, they have their own `LayoutParams`, like so:

```
pf.setLayoutParams(new ConstraintLayout.LayoutParams(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

or

```
parentView.addView(pf, new LayoutParams(LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
```

Comment: `android.view.ViewGroup$LayoutParams cannot be cast to android.widget.LinearLayout$LayoutParams`

Comment: well, the main diff is that in the first code we are creating a new TextView with that settings already. In the second one, we are adding into an existing view, and also we are setting those parameters. For the cast problem, i think you must cast the proper class

Answer (score 98):

There is another way to achieve same result. In case you need to set only one parameter, for example 'height':

```
TextView textView = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.text_view);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = textView.getLayoutParams();
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
textView.setLayoutParams(params);
```

Comment: This works great. If this is done on `LinearLayout` it doesn't appear that `ll.invalidate()` is necessary. Why?

Comment: I guess we'll never know

Answer (score 57):

Solution for change `TextView` width to **wrap content**.

```
textView.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT; 
textView.requestLayout();  
// Call requestLayout() for redraw your TextView when your TextView is already drawn (laid out) (eg: you update TextView width when click a Button). 
// If your TextView is drawing you may not need requestLayout() (eg: you change TextView width inside onCreate()). However if you call it, it still working well => for easy: always use requestLayout()

// Another useful example
// textView.getLayoutParams().width = 200; // For change `TextView` width to 200 pixel
```

Comment: Simple and right solution, because it doesn't override other parameters.

Comment: Marked my anwer for delete as this is much simpler.

Comment: This is the best solution

Answer (score 19):

A little update on this post: if you are using ktx within your Android project, there is a little helper method that makes updating LayoutParams a lot easier.

If you want to update e.g. only the width you can do that with the following line in Kotlin.

```
tv.updateLayoutParams { width = WRAP_CONTENT }
```

Answer (score 5):

I am posting android Java base multi line edittext.

```
EditText editText = findViewById(R.id.editText);/* edittext access */

ViewGroup.LayoutParams params  =  editText.getLayoutParams(); 
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
editText.setLayoutParams(params); /* Gives as much height for multi line*/

editText.setSingleLine(false); /* Makes it Multi line */
```

Answer (score 1):

I think this code answer your question

```
RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams) 
holder.desc1.getLayoutParams();
params.height = RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
holder.desc1.setLayoutParams(params);
```