# Programmatically setting TextView to RelativeLayout.CENTER_OF_PARENT

Tags: java, android, xml, android-layout, android-relativelayout

I am just learning Java and XML and am trying to set a TextView to be in the center of its parent RelativeLayout. My App only loads when I comment out the last 3 lines before the `setContentView(homeScreen)`

Here is my XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity">

</RelativeLayout>
```

Here is my Java:

```
package com.example.android.testerapp1;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);


    TextView homeScreen = new TextView(this);
    homeScreen.setText("Welcome to Test App 001" + "\nThis TextView was created dynamically in Java!");
    homeScreen.setTextSize(24);
    homeScreen.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
    homeScreen.setCursorVisible(true);
    homeScreen.setPadding(16,56,16,56);
    homeScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
    homeScreen.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

    //dynamically set width to dp (converted to pixels ~600) and height to 'wrap content'
    // convert dp amount to pixels for size
    final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
    int pixelWidth = (int) (2000 / scale + 0.5f);

    homeScreen.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(pixelWidth , ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));

    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = (RelativeLayout.LayoutParams)homeScreen.getLayoutParams();
    params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT);
    homeScreen.setLayoutParams(params);


    setContentView(homeScreen);
    }
}
```

I have seen this sort of post about 10 times now and they all have the same solution which I can't seem to implement correctly, it may be another part of my code? Possibly where I set the width and height using`setLayoutParams`also?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `setContentView()` call is supposed to be used to set the layout of the full screen. What you're doing currently in your Activity code is setting just a TextView as the full view of the screen, so the Activity has no reference to the XML layout that you created. This is why your 3 lines of code at the end fail, because the `TextView` is trying to setup its `LayoutParams` for how its parent should place and measure it, however it has no parent in this context. What I would recommend doing is giving an `id` attribute to the `RelativeLayout` in the XML to get a reference to it in `Activity` code like so:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="home_screen_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".MainActivity"/>
```

Then in your `Activity` code, adjust it so that you call with the resource id of your XML file. If we assume it's called `act_main.xml` in the layout folder of your resources directory (i.e. in `src/main/resources/layout/act_main.xml`), you would call `setContentView(R.layout.act_main)` as the first line in `onCreate()` after the `super()` call so that the framework has an opportunity to parse your XML and inflate it (i.e. instantiate, make calculations on the size and 
 determine placement of its components among other things). After that, use `findViewById(R.id.home_screen_layout)` to get a reference to that `RelativeLayout` so that you may create a new `TextView` and add it to your already inflated layout.

```
package com.example.android.testerapp1;

import android.graphics.Color;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.RelativeLayout;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    // make your view components private members as findViewById calls are expensive for the framework
    private RelativeLayout homeScreenLayout;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Have the activity inflate the XML file with your RelativeLayout
        setContentView(R.layout.act_main);

        // Now that it is inflated, get a reference to that parent
        homeScreenLayout = (RelativeLayout) findViewById(R.id.home_screen_layout);

        // Dynamically create a TextView associated with this Activity's context
        TextView homeScreen = new TextView(this);
        homeScreen.setText("Welcome to Test App 001" + "\nThis TextView was created dynamically in Java!");
        homeScreen.setTextSize(24);
        homeScreen.setTextColor(Color.CYAN);
        homeScreen.setCursorVisible(true);
        homeScreen.setPadding(16,56,16,56);
        homeScreen.setBackgroundColor(Color.BLACK);
        homeScreen.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);

        //dynamically set width to dp (converted to pixels ~600) and height to 'wrap content'
        // convert dp amount to pixels for size
        final float scale = getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density;
        int pixelWidth = (int) (2000 / scale + 0.5f);

        // Adjust the placement in the parent
        RelativeLayout.LayoutParams params = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(pixelWidth , RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT)    
        params.addRule(RelativeLayout.CENTER_IN_PARENT, RelativeLayout.TRUE); // make sure to use the function which takes a boolean value for rules like CENTER_IN_PARENT
        homeScreen.setLayoutParams(params); // Add these parameters to the textview

        // Let the layout know about your newly created textview so that it can re-draw its canvas
        homeScreenLayout.addView(homeScreen);

    }
}
```

As a note, I will add that a of what you're doing can be done in the XML with relative ease, but since you asked about setting it programmatically specifically, I won't go into detail on that aspect. But if you're interested in some structured resources, I would recommend checking out the [Android Developer Guide](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/index.html), specifically the section on [XML layouts and how they interact with Activities](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/layout-resource.html)

**EDIT:** Note the changes I made to the code for the Activity. The major pieces are first inflating the empty RelativeLayout xml with `setContentView(int id)`, and then adding the other `TextView` to the given layout. There was a minor error in the code I presented concerning the `CENTER_IN_PARENT` line. According to the [docs](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.html#addRule(int, int)), you must use the `addRule(int, int)` version of the function when adding rules that use a boolean value.

Comment: This makes complete sense, since it has no parent to go to the center of. However I'm trying to create the TextView dynamically in Java as an exercise, so your answer is only partly helpful. I think I need to add the TextView to the RelativeLayout first and `setContentView` to the RelativeLayout? I have tried `RelativeLayout homeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.homeLayout);` and then `homeLayout.addView(homeScreen);` but it doesnt run even after changing to `setContentView(homeLayout);`....

Comment: Even when I dont use `homeLayout.addView(homeScreen);` and ignore my `homeScreen` completely it still crashes. I believe the problem is in `RelativeLayout homeLayout = (RelativeLayout)findViewById(R.id.homeLayout);` then `setContentView(homeLayout);` app doesnt even show the 'Hello World' from my preview window, it just goes black and closes. Is there a way of adding the homeScreen to the RelativeLayout in java and still call `setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)`?

Comment: Well, I'll say that if you want to create all the layout components programmatically, including your `RelativeLayout`, then you would instantiate all of your views and pass in the `RelativeLayout` to the correct `setContentView(View view, ViewGroup.LayoutParams param)` call (note the function parameters as documented [here](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setContentView(android.view.View))). Since you just want to add the TextView dynamically, you call `setContentView(int id)` and then use `findViewById()` to to the `RelativeLayout`

Answer (score 0):

You can set width and height on the constructor and then use it

```
Relative.LayoutParams(int width, int height)
```

so you need to do like:

```
homeScreen.setLayoutParams(width , height);
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error that i'm not passing two 'int' to 'setLayoutParams' method - I initially tried your method but after researching like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9678785/android-setting-layoutparams-programmatically & https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854492/setting-width-to-wrap-content-for-textview-through-code