# How to programmatically set a TextView width and height to Wrap Content

Tags: android, nullpointerexception

I am writing a table programmatically from an SQLite database.

In a loop I am generating  needed `TextViews` and am attempting to wrap the data in a `TextView` called `descCol` when the data is longer than the existing screen allows.

Suggestions to do this were offered in the following link:
[Setting width to wrap_content for TextView through code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854492/setting-width-to-wrap-content-for-textview-through-code/47366121#47366121)

However when using either of the suggested methods I'm getting a `java.lang.NullPointerException`.

Here's my code example:

```
TextView descCol = new TextView(this);
descCol.getLayoutParams().width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
```

In this case debug shows it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the `getLayoutParams()` line.

Also I've tried:

```
TextView descCol = new TextView(this);
ViewGroup.LayoutParams params = descCol.getLayoutParams();
params.height = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
params.width = ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT;
descCol.setLayoutParams(params);
```

In this case debug shows it throws a `java.lang.NullPointerException` on the `params.height` line.

Debug shows that in either case after performing the `getLayoutParams()` method, params is equal to null, apparently throwing the exception.

I've tried to assign other parameters first to `descCol` (textcolor, text, gravity etc.) prior to the `getLayoutParams()` but get the same result.

Suggestions as to how to avoid the `java.lang.NullPointerException` would be appreciated.

Comment: A `View` doesn't have `LayoutParams` until you've set them, or the `View` gets added to a `ViewGroup`. In both of your snippets, `getLayoutParams()` is returning null.

Answer (score 11):

Also I was able to accomplish my task programmatically by simply using the setWidth and setHeight methods.

```
textview.setWidth(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
textview.setHeight(ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
```

Comment: I'm using this inside a Google Maps marker and it works, but also adds a ton of white space below all of my Views.

Comment: I think this will set the width and height to -1 pixel, assuming ViewGroup.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT returns -1.

Answer (score 4):

**Try this way:**

```
  LinearLayout.LayoutParams textParam = new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                        (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 1.0f);

    textView.setLayoutParams(textParam);
```

Answer (score 1):

Why are you using getLayoutParams() when you didnt even set the layout Params ?
You need to setLayout Params first. like this.

```
 TextView view = new TextView(this);
 view.setText("example textview ");
 //adding layout properties 
 view.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams
                    (LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, 0));
// add the textview to the parentLayout
parentLayout.addView(view);
```

Comment: Thanks all. In the link above they had neglected to include the view.setLayoutParams method in their sample code.                                             Note: In your sample code Mezzy there is a typo (an extra ');' at the end). Hey, it happens to the best of us

Comment: @Bill Thanks for pointing .. updated it. You can up vote my answer if it helped you.