# Setting Height and Width of textView based on the text

Tags: android, kotlin

I have a textView function that's create text view

`fun createTextView(text: String, index: Int): TextView`

Now I'm trying to make the textView height and width based on the text I input

```
val words = arrayListOf("abc")

I tried 

for ((wordIndex, i) in words.withIndex()){
            val textView = createTextView(i,wordIndex)
            textView.y = shuffleXList[wordIndex]*83F
            textView.x=  shuffleYList[wordIndex]*83F
            textView.measure(0, 0)
            textView.height = textView.measuredHeight
            textView.width = textView.measuredWidth
            textView.setBackgroundColor(BgColor)
}
```

This is what I got
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ltuGd.png)

how do I adjust the weight and height such that the color is only around the text?

Comment: You can just take a textview in your xml file and give wrap_content height and width to that and it should work.

Comment: Hello I cannot modify the text in xml since I'm trying to programmatically do this on a separate file.

Comment: What is the purpose of having a textview this way?

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4854492/setting-width-to-wrap-content-for-textview-through-code

Comment: Oh because in this assignment I'm trying to display random words into a textview and I'm not supposed to edit it from xml file

Comment: You can add textview in xml file and still change the text of that afterwards.

Comment: thanks! I used the link pykerepaer sent me! thank you for helping!

Comment: Hello Karan, just curious how do I do that? After running my program. The textviews show in my emulator, but I did not see it on my xml file.

Answer (score 1):

You have to try this one

```
textView.setText("abc");
textView.measure(0, 0);
textView.getMeasuredWidth();
textView.getMeasuredHeight();
```